# How can I print my admit card from Gmail?

Tags: gmail, printing

I received an email today from XYZ foundation and they have invited me for written test. But the problem is instead of attaching admit card as pdf, it is in somehow formatted in the email only. First there is some text that notifies me of rules and all and then there is the admit card. I have no idea how they do that but it is. Now if I print the entire email, it gets screwed up as I dont want the text and also half of admit card is on one page and half on other. How can I download or print that rectangular array of admit card only?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome, try this:

- Click and drag over the card to highlight only the part you want
- right click on the highlighted area and choose 'Print'.
- In the print options check 'selection only'.

The print preview should show that only the highlighted part will be printed, which should hopefully fit on one page.

Comment: cannot select a particular area by dragging... it only highlights text.

Comment: This probably means that the card itself is an image.

Even though you can't highlight the image you might be able to start selecting a little before the image itself, then drag down and get it. Then follow the steps I indicated earlier.

Another solution could be to forward the email to yourself and before clicking 'send', delete all the text content you don't want. Then print that email after you received it.

Comment: the forwarding method  worked